# Autocomplete input resets form with react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api, react-final-form

I am trying to add a form validation to a react form which contains Autocomplete input has one of the field, On selection of the auto suggested value form gets reset automatically.

Comment: Can you supply some relevant code?

Comment: Or even better: a sandbox.

Comment: I just ran into this issue. Let me create a sandbox and share